# Unitils with Hibernate4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unitils

I'm trying to upgrade an Struts/Spring application from Hibernate 3.1 to Hibernate 4.3.

I'm using Untils for my database tests, and under Hibernate 3.1, the tests were working correctly.  Under Hibernate 4.3, the tests are failing with the following error:

```
org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Could not find a configuring @HibernateSessionFactory annotation or custom config method
    at org.unitils.orm.common.OrmModule.getConfiguredPersistenceUnit(OrmModule.java:186)
    at org.unitils.orm.common.OrmModule.getPersistenceUnit(OrmModule.java:147)
    at org.unitils.orm.common.OrmModule.injectOrmPersistenceUnitIntoTestObject(OrmModule.java:333)
    at org.unitils.orm.common.OrmModule$OrmTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(OrmModule.java:379)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils$UnitilsTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(Unitils.java:273)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:181)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

For example, the following test will fail:

```
@SpringApplicationContext({ configurationFiles })
public class SettlementDAOImplTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {
    @HibernateSessionFactory
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    public void type() throws Exception {
        assertThat(SettlementDAOImpl.class, notNullValue());
    }
}
```

I've checked my libraries, and I'm loading the correct versions of Unitils and Hibernate, and my sessionFactory is defined as a `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`

At this point, I'm not even sure how to proceed.  It appears that Unitils is looking for a hibernate3.localSessionFactoryBean.  What should I be looking for to troubleshoot this problem?

In my applicationcontext file, the sessionFactory looks like:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>Settlement.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                com.acteva.commons.util.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.provider">javassist</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">
                auto
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="entityInterceptorBean" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to explanation below:

Source: http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-hibernate.html

Under the hoods, hibernate uses an instance of org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration or org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration for loading configuration files and registering mapped classes, depending on whether you're using hibernate the classic way or whether you use hibernate with annotation. By default, Unitils uses org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration. If you're using mapping files only and you don't have the hibernate annotations extension in your classpath, you can change this by setting following property:

HibernateModule.configuration.implClassName=org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Comment: Where is this property set?

Answer (score 0):

@Ozan Tabak : We are using the following property, and we encounter the same issue.

```
HibernateModule.configuration.implClassName=org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
```

It looks like it's a bug in unitils, [which doesn't seem to support hibernate4](https://unitils.atlassian.net/browse/UNI-244)

> Unitils ver 3.3 does not support loading sessionFactory by
> @SpringApplicationContext when sessionFactory is defined by
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.
>
> Unitils searches for
> "org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" and can't
> find the class because for hibernate 4 there is new namespace
> "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean".

Since this issue is there since September 2012, I don't expect a bug fix soon.

Comment: Hit the same or similar problem when trying to port unitils tests to Hibernate 5. Did you find any solution to the problem?

Comment: @gnomie : Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Thanks! So I am looking for a replacement... any suggestion?